# MySQL - How do I have one column reference multiple entries in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a character card database for a role playing game using MySQL. I am setting up the character cards so that each character is able to have multiple skills.

Here is a rough sketch of an example card:

[image: Sample Card]

So far I have a two tables set up, called CHARACTERS and SKILLS:

> CHARACTERS (id, last_name, first_name, character_name, skills)
>
> SKILLS (id, name, description)

I am looking for a way for the skills column in the CHARACTERS table to be able to somehow store multiple skills listed in the SKILLS table.

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Both answers so far point to the advantages of a related `skills` table. In general, I suggest you read about database normalization. Just as a starting point, I suggest you read [this entry in the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a skills column in the Characters table, you'll want to tap into the functionality of a relational database and use a Character_Skills lookup table:
Character_Skills (char_id, skill_id) {char_id maps to Characters.id and skill_id maps to Skills.id}

Then you can join the tables.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be through a separate table which would list all of the skills for a given character.  It would look something like this:

CHARACTER_SKILLS (character_id, skill_id)

Answer (score 1):

Tom and Dave Jemison have it right.  I'd just add some color, because we all love these kinds of games:

```
CHARACTERS       (char_id, last_name, first_name, character_name)
SKILLS           (skill_id, skill_name, skill_description)
CHARACTER_SKILLS (char_id, skill_id, skill_level)
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
SELECT c.char_id, c.character_name, s.skill_name, cs.skill_level
FROM CHARACTERS c LEFT JOIN CHARACTER_SKILLS cs ON c.char_id=cs.char_id
                  LEFT JOIN SKILLS s on cs.skill_id=s.skill_id;
```

And get something roughly like this:

```
1, ers81239, mysql, 10
1, ers81239, stackoverflow, 10
1, ers81239, funny_examples, 0
2, other_character, mysql, 4
etc.
```